# Swift - why can't lazy properties be readily made read only

Tags: ios, swift, lazy-loading, readonly

Can anyone please explain this comment re lazy properties by neuburg in iOS 9 swift fundamentals book ...

"There are some minor holes in the language: lazy instance properties can’t have setter observers, and there’s no  lazy let  (so you can’t readily make a lazy instance property read-only)" .... Particularly about no lazy let preventing ability for read only

Comment: But you can make it `private(set) lazy var x`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Apple [documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

> You must always declare a lazy property as a variable (with the var keyword), because its initial value might not be retrieved until after instance initialization completes. Constant properties must always have a value before initialization completes, and therefore cannot be declared as lazy.

But if you want do get a value lazy from a class/struct and want to be sure that nobody can write back to that value then simply use a func with a return value. Or like milos said - a private(set) on a lazy property. (which is not the same thing) So somehow everything is possible. :)

Comment: thx. Understand that... What's confusing me is that the author's statement implies to me that ...the fact that a lazy property can't be declared let is the main reason why lazy can't be read-only.  Which then implies... If lazy could be declared let then there'd be no problem having a read only lazy property ....Perhaps I'm reading too much into it

Comment: No, that's not the case, and I am sure matt knows this. But if you want do get a value lazy from a class/struct and want to be sure that nobody can write back to that value then simply use a func with a return value.

Comment: It's pretty stupid that there's no `lazy let`. I really hate it when any programming language wants you to write syntax just to satisfy their internal implementation of things. This is not developer-friendly. No matter how it's implemented, `lazy let` should be made a syntax sugar (or whatever) to just create lazily instantiated value immutable. I believe immutable lazy properties are more common than mutable ones. Think of instantiated dependencies, I guess that's the most common use case. And they are not mutable.